# Python - Why does it prints "none"?

Tags: python

```
i = 1
input_number = int(input("Input a digit you wish to count: "))


def count(n):
    global i
    n = int(n/10)
    if n > 0:
        i = i+1
        count(n)
    else:
        j = i
        print(f"j={j}")
        return j


j = count(input_number)
print(f"i={i}")
print(j)
```

I'm trying to use a recursive way to print the digits of a number. I used a global counter to count, and can print the global counter as result. However, my question is -  why can't I make the function to return the counter and print the function result directly? It returns None somehow.

Comment: It doesn't return `None` "somehow". It returns `None` when you don't return anything ele. You don't return anything in the true branch of your `if` statement. Change `count(n)` to `return count(n)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `count` function does not always return a value, so in those cases, it returns `None`.

If `n`  is greater than `0`, no `return` is encountered.

> ```
>    if n > 0:
>        i = i+1
>        count(n)
> ```

You were likely wanting:

```
    if n > 0:
        i = i+1
        return count(n)
```

Please also note that if you want integer division, you can use `//`. E.g. `n = int(n/10)` can be `n = n // 10` or just `n //= 10`.